# How to start a telegram bot with different tokens, on 1 server in golang

Tags: go

There is a piece of working code that launches a bot to receive webhooks.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI("MyAwesomeBotToken")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    bot.Debug = true

    log.Printf("Authorized on account %s", bot.Self.UserName)

    _, err = bot.SetWebhook(tgbotapi.NewWebhookWithCert("https://example.com:8443/"+bot.Token, "cert.pem"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    info, err := bot.GetWebhookInfo()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if info.LastErrorDate != 0 {
        log.Printf("Telegram callback failed: %s", info.LastErrorMessage)
    }
    updates := bot.ListenForWebhook("/" + bot.Token)
    go http.ListenAndServeTLS("0.0.0.0:8443", "cert.pem", "key.pem", nil)

    for update := range updates {
        log.Printf("%+v\n", update)
    }
}
```

Library for golang - **tgbotapi**

When I try to launch another bot on the same server, with the same code,
but with a different token, of course, the following happens, the bot is successfully authorized but does not respond to commands, or it simply does not receive a webhook, who knows the reason?

I turn off 1 bot, then the second one starts without problems, at the same time they do not want to..

Comment: Do you change port 8443 to something else for the second bot?

Comment: yes, works) thanks ,it turns out that there can be only 1 bot on 1 port?

Comment: Yes, unless you use a reverse proxy: https://madhead.me/posts/nginx-tg-bots/